# Finding why a TCP connection drops

Tags: router, connection, tcp

Two months ago the german Audible shop relaunched their site to be more like their parent company Amazon. Since then I've not been able to download my purchases.

The culprit is my Netgear WGR614v8 router. If I connect the cable modem directly to the computer, or use a different router, everything works like it used to.

However with the Netgear even Audible's own iPhone app is not able to complete a download. Things start at full speed and after some non-reproducible number of megabytes they just stop coming completely. After 10 minutes of this I usually cancel.

I made a Wireshark dump. I can't really read these, but towards the end there's a "TCP Previous segment lost" and then several "TCP Dup ACK".

Comment: The TCP errors you are seeing are common to a flakey connection.  Which is probably the wifi connection.  If you connect to a wired port on the WGR614, does it do the same thing?

Comment: The computer was wired, and even the WGR worked fine until the site relaunch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I contacted Audible and after numerous discussions got this reply:

> We have found that certain ISPs and router setups have caused
>   customers to experience Wi-Fi downloading issues over the past week or
>   so. Based on your information, it sounds as if your setup may have
>   been part of this glitch. We actually implemented a fix to this issue
>   yesterday and the fix seems to be working, so I would suggest trying
>   to download via your home Wi-Fi again at this time.
>
> If you still encounter downloading issues, please power cycle you
>   router by unplugging the router for 30 seconds and plugging it back
>   in. Next, please try download the title one more time. If you still
>   find that your home Wi-Fi will not download your titles to your iPod,
>   please try the following steps on the device.
>
> 1. Please tap on the "settings" option on your iPod.
> 2. Please select "general" from this page.
> 3. Next, please tap Reset>Reset Network Settings
> 4. Finally, after your phone reboots, please go back to the settings page, select Wi-Fi, and turn Wi-Fi back on.
> 5. Please connect to your home network
>
> After taking care of this process, please try downloading your title a
>   final time. You should be able to download without incident.

Comment: It was still broken in March, and also seems to affect Vimeo downloads. What fixed both was installing DD-WRT fimrware instead of what Netgear shipped.